# Optimization flag (-O3) fixes multiple definition error

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

Using gcc 4.7.1

I noticed today after I got a redefinition error compiling with default optimization(-O0), that it can be "fixed" by simply compiling with -O2 or -O3 optimization flags.

**Why would this be?**

Comment: Violations of the One Definition Rule are undefined behaviour

Comment: Your "default optimization" is also known as "no optimizations".

Comment: @Deduplicator: It's no optimization effort, which is not quite the same.  Some optimizations still get performed if they are (1) effectively free and (2) don't negatively impact debugging.  For example, turning `do { } while (true);` into an unconditional branch.